# OS X Mavericks - Have to pull mouse down on full-screen app to see dock

Tags: dock, macos

Updated to Mavericks yesterday, pretty happy with the speed boost it brought, but I've run into one problem:

Whenever I'm running a full-screen app, for example mail, and I want my dock to show, I really have to pull the mouse down. Just "throwing" it down to the bottom of the screen with a one-finger swipe no longer does the trick; I have to keep my finger on the trackpad to get the dock to show.

I asked a colleague and he noticed the same thing, only in a full-screen app, is there a way to turn this "feature" off, or is this a bug?

Comment: That doesn't quite describe the behavior I'm seeing. In fact, I'm really not sure what it is, as it seems to be a bit different each time. There must be some documentation of this somewhere, and one would hope there's a way to configure it too. In the meantime, this really doesn't work for me.

Comment: I've found [a method](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112513/4395) that works for me every time.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the new gesture in Mavericks.  It used to be that you had to pull the mouse/trackpad down twice in quick succession.  Now you just have to hold the mouse/trackpad down at the bottom of the screen.  I had not figured this one out before reading your post, so thank you.  I have found nothing about this anywhere else. Apparently, this gesture cannot be changed.

Comment: Well, that sucks. Thanks for your update though! Guess I won't work with full-screen apps, because it really annoys me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the Dock to appear for full-screen app, *rest* (don't click) your finger on the mouse anywhere on the screen, *while swiping* to the bottom of the screen. The Dock will then appear immediately when you hit bottom.

---

Note that none of the other methods described here work reliably for me, but this one does every time.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, it was actually the same mechanic before. The difference is that now you have to do the second swipe **slowly**. And it's really annoying.